# How to comment lines in rails html.erb files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Am a newbie to rails ,
 please let me know the way to comment out a single line and also to comment out
 a block of lines  in *.html.erb files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Block comments in html.erb templates in rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127644/block-comments-in-html-erb-templates-in-rails) for blocks, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774841/best-way-to-add-comments-in-erb for single lines

Answer (score 229, accepted):

[ruby on rails notes](http://web.archive.org/web/20110403150152/http://www.railsnotes.com/34-commenting-out-erb-code-in-rails-htmlerb/) has a very nice blogpost about commenting in erb-files

the short version is

to comment a single line use

```
<%# commented line %>
```

to comment a whole block use a `if false` to surrond your code like this

```
<% if false %>
code to comment
<% end %>
```

Comment: +1 For solving my issue, but I've found it very ugly. To comment one line I must use 3 additional characters, and the block comment is nothing but code that will be not executed - no other color coding that makes it very unpractical to see which code is not executed on first look.

Comment: For single line, you don't need the hyphens e.g. <%# my comment %>

Comment: A comment_block helper function would be awesome. Maybe when I gain a little more experience with Rails (I'm pretty new), I will create a pull request

Comment: @gotqn Then you will LOVE [HAML](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#haml_comments_)!

Answer (score 28):

Note that if you want to comment out a single line of printing erb you should do like this

```
<%#= ["Buck", "Papandreou"].join(" you ") %>
```

Comment: This also works for multiple lines

Answer (score 9):

### This is CLEANEST, SIMPLEST ANSWER for CONTIGUOUS NON-PRINTING Ruby Code:

*The below also happens to answer the Original Poster's question without, the **"ugly" conditional code** that some commenters have mentioned.*

---

1. **CONTIGUOUS NON-PRINTING Ruby Code**

   - This will work in any **mixed** language **Rails View** file, e.g, `*.html.erb, *.js.erb, *.rhtml`, etc.
   - This should also work with **STD OUT/printing** code, e.g. `<%#= f.label :title %>`
   - **DETAILS**:

     Rather than use rails brackets on each line and commenting in front of each starting bracket as we usually do like this:

     ```
       <%# if flash[:myErrors] %>
         <%# if flash[:myErrors].any? %>
           <%# if @post.id.nil? %>
             <%# if @myPost!=-1 %>
               <%# @post = @myPost %>
             <%# else %>
               <%# @post = Post.new %>
             <%# end %>
           <%# end %>
         <%# end %>
       <%# end %>
     ```

     **YOU CAN INSTEAD add only one comment (hashmark/poundsign) to the first open Rails bracket if you write your code as one large block... LIKE THIS:**

     ```
       <%# 
         if flash[:myErrors] then
           if flash[:myErrors].any? then
             if @post.id.nil? then
               if @myPost!=-1 then
                 @post = @myPost 
               else 
                 @post = Post.new 
               end 
             end 
           end 
         end 
       %>
     ```

Comment: @TejasKale sorry... not sure what you mean? --> the chances of **YOUR** code or **MY** code** working?

Comment: your method above would generate errors if the code is incorrect, which will almost always be the case with me :)

Comment: first off, no need for the `then`. Second, this completely destroy the idea behind `MVC`. Keep your logic in a helper or in your controller. -1

Comment: @TheChamp I do appreciate you stating why you are downgrading; that's helpful for everyone.  But, you are wrong: my answer, adequately addresses the question, and *is* correct. If you have a BETTER way of doing it, e.g. without the use of `then`, then you should add your own answer. Beyond that, the OP does **not** ask about MVC theory, or the Rails paradigm. Finally, if you do believe it is a *BAD QUESTION* (because commenting out logic breaks Rails MVC best practices) then you should downvote the **QUESTION** not my answer...

Comment: @TomLord with respect, yes you are missing something... the `if` statement is irrelevant.. I am simply using it as an example of a block of code that he might want to comment out, and the use of an OPEN comment tag at the beginning and a CLOSE comment tag at the end