# Missing Template Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates, cloud9-ide, gemfile

When I run my code on *Cloud9 IDE*, the next error appears:

```
Missing partial submissions/_submission with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates" * "/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views" * "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/app/views"
```

I have a **Submissions Controller** and my create code is like this:

```
def create
 @submission = Submission.new(submission_params)

 respond_to do |format|
  if @submission.save
    format.html { redirect_to root_path}
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @submission }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @submission.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

I don't know which is my error and where to locate it.

Plus, a full stack text http://pastebin.com/YnyQeetU

The code of index.html.erb http://pastebin.com/fZbXd0Wk

Comment: `Missing partial submissions/_submission` - as your error says you are missing partial `_submission.html.erb` . Where you have used it and what is the path to partial ?

Comment: @dkp What do you mean by _submission.html.erb? I do not have that file, I have some files which names are _form, edit, index, show and new .html.erb

Comment: Please check your views, there might be some place where you are rendering `_submission.html.erb` partial. It would be better if you can add your relevant view which is getting rendered here.

Comment: @dkp There is no reference to _submission.html.erb in /views/submissions. The most likely thing is this line of code

    <!--<%= link_to 'New Submission', new_submission_path %>-->

Comment: Can you just add the complete stack trace ?

Comment: Replace the line `<!--<%= link_to 'New Submission', new_submission_path %>-->` with `<!--<%#= link_to 'New Submission', new_submission_path %>-->` will fix your  problem

Comment: The full stack

http://pastebin.com/YnyQeetU

Comment: `submissions/index.html.erb` - please add this view code to your question.

Comment: `<!--<%= render @submissions %>-->` - This line of code is causing the problem. Why you have added html comment here ? If you want to comment this line of code, you should do `<%#= render @submissions %>`

Comment: It is not my code, just recieved it.

 Why is it wrong to have that line here? Is it supposed to be in another part of the code or I just comment it and everything should work fine?

Comment: It depends on your requirement. If you need to render that partial, then add the `_submissions.html.erb` to `views/submissions/` path and make use of partial. If you just don't need it now, comment it out .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code is causing the problem.

```
<!--<%= render @submissions %>--> 
#<!-- --> This is used to comment an HTML tag
```

If you do not want to render the partial you can simply comment that out as follows:

```
<%#= render @submissions %>
#<%# %> This is the way to comment embedded ruby code
```

Answer (score 1):

Though the line is commented in HTML, the server tag is still being executed. Try to comment the server tag with `<%#= link_to 'New Submission', new_submission_path %>`. This will stop executing the server tag and you will not get the error.

More reference: [How to comment lines in rails html.erb files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901619/how-to-comment-lines-in-rails-html-erb-files)

Comment: <!--<%= render @submissions %>-->

Comment: Replace that with `<!--<%#= render @submissions %>-->`. Note the hash tag(#).

Comment: That is what whas wrong. Is this line supposed to appear in another part of the code or it is out of context and I erase it and everything will be fine?

Thank you! :)