# How to comment out a Ruby on Rails block in Atom

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments, atom-editor

I try to comment out a Rails block in Atom.

When I use CTRL+/ I get:

Before:

```
  <%= form_for @subscriber do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Name" %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, placeholder: "Email" %>
    <% f.select :source, ["Search Engine", "Social Media", "Word of Mouth", "Other"],
      prompt: "How did you hear about me?" %>
    <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
```

After:

```
  <%# <%= form_for @subscriber do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Name" %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, placeholder: "Email" %>
    <% f.select :source, ["Search Engine", "Social Media", "Word of Mouth", "Other"],
      prompt: "How did you hear about me?" %>
    <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %> %>
```

Somehow Atom's default blocking does not work. As you can see, only the first line will be blocked.

How can I make sure I can block a Rails text properly?

I also tried using the Atom "ERB Comment-package", https://atom.io/packages/erb-comment. But this does not help.

Even if I try manually

```
  <!-- %= form_for @subscriber do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Name" %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, placeholder: "Email" %>
    <% f.select :source, ["Search Engine", "Social Media", "Word of Mouth", "Other"],
      prompt: "How did you hear about me?" %>
    <%= f.submit %>
  <% end % -->
```

I still does only partially comment out the block and I even don't know the shortcut to the  way of commenting out in Atom

All these [Block comments in html.erb templates in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127644/block-comments-in-html-erb-templates-in-rails) solutions don't work in Atom. And besides, it does not give a proper Atom short-cut.

Comment: There is a huge difference between ERB comment lines `<%#` which output nothing (besides the trailing whitespace) and HTML comments `<!--` which just cause the client to ignore the line. It not very unexpected that Atom doesn't know how to block comment/uncomment ERB as comments in embedded languages are lot more complex to parse then just adding/removing comment characters to the beginning of a line.